# Changing input format for Android calendar

Tags: calendar

I have a Nexus 4.  For the calendar, you have to scroll to enter a time, which is inconvenient for events starting at :30 (30 minutes past the hour).  On the same phone, for the alarm clock, you manually enter the time using a keypad-type display.  Is there anyway to use the keypad-type display rather than scrolling for the calendar function?

Answer (score 3):

When creating the event click on the time that you need to change:
[image: Click time]

Then when the set time pop-up comes up press on the number instead of scrolling.

[image: Click actual number] [image: Input number]